# Laravel: Class 'Google_Client' not found

Tags: laravel, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use google-api-php-client in my laravel project.

I'm installed the package using "composer require google/apiclient" command and also added the following line in composer.json.

```
    {
       "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google"
            ],
        }
    }
```

and run this command too "composer dump-autoload"

But whenever i try to create new Google Client object, it keeps returning fatal error : Google_Client not found.

Can anybody help me with this issue?.Thanks.

I have already tried following ways.
(1) use Google_Client; 
(2) $client = new Google_Client;
(3) $client = new \Google_Client;

Comment: remove this "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google" and dump autoload again .no need this.i have tried it without that and its working fine

Comment: i used latest version from https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client and laravel 5.8

Comment: There really isn't any need to setup a class map when you install a package using composer. Because the package is installed in the vendor directory, it will be autoloaded by composer. If `composer dump` doesn't fix (although it should), try reinstalling the package.

Comment: I removed "vendor" line and autoload again.But still not works. I also tried deleting  the whole vendor folder and reinstalled it.Still not helps...

Comment: I won't put this in as the definitive answer, but for me this worked: use \Google_Client;

Comment: @MichaelHinds Your suggestion also works for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google_Client, Google_Service_YouTube etc are aliases to Google\Client and Google\Service\Youtube respectively.
To import them, use:

```
use Google\Client as Google_Client;
use Google\Service\YouTube as Google_Service_YouTube;
```